# Rails 3 validation, multiple fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

Have 4 fields (alpha, beta, gamma, delta), at least 1 of them must have a value, ie not be nil/empty/blank. How can I create a validation to make sure of that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
validate :something_must_be_set

def something_must_be_set
  unless alpha || beta || gamma || delta
    errors.add(:base, "Alpha, Beta, Gamma or Delta must be present.")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, kept writing validates, instead of validate.